# Django: 3-level base class and Meta class ignored?

Tags: django

I'm having the following setup in a Django 2 app:

```py
class Base1(models.Model):
   # ... some fields here...
      class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = [
            'brand',
            'name'
        ]

class Base2(Base1):
    # ... some more fields here...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Concrete(Base2):
    pass
```

The `Concrete` class doesn't seem to have the `unique_together` requirement that's present in `Base1`.

Is this expected? If it is, how can I make sure that `Concrete` has the constraint while keeping things DRY?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to derive `Base2`'s `Meta` from `Base1`'s.

```
# ...
class Base2(Base1):
    # ... some more fields here...
    class Meta(Base1.Meta):
        abstract = True
# ...
```

See this documentation for [meta inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).